# `UL` - element has the width as `100%` - still children drops on new line

Tags: html, css

My `div` has the limited `width` and `overflow-x:auto` and it's children `ul` has the `width` of `100%`, still children of `ul` drops in new line. the childrens `li` has the `float:left` property.

I require `li` should not drop. i need to add `li`  by dynamic.

here is the demo:

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  list-style:none;
}

.parent{
  width:300px;
  overflow-x:auto;
  background:green;
}
ul{
  width:100%; 
}
ul li{
  float:left; 
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any one guide me here.

Comment: So you want `li` width 100px in one line with horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: @RyanVincent - the width is not `300px` here. the width is `100%` that's whats the question is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep all `li`'s on one line with fixed width you can use `overflow-x: auto` and `white-space: nowrap` on `ul`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  background: green;
}
ul {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: hi Nenad, I know this solution. here, the UL has the width of `100%` we should not think about `500px` here at all. so the `li` has float left - what is the issue?

Comment: Parent has `width: 300px;` and `ul` has `width: 100%` or `300px` in this case so that is why `li`'s go to new line.

Comment: ok. makes scenes. using float - do not we have any other approach? if so suggest. thanks for your response and answer.

Comment: Do you want `li`'s with fixed `width` and scroll-bar, or you want dynamic width on `li`'s?